# C# Fluent NHibernate 0-1 0-many 1-many Mapping with custom rules

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I need to configure NHibernate Mappings using Fluent library for some relations of my DB.
I created a **Web Api MVC** Project on VS 2017 with **NHibernate v4.1.1.4000** and **FluentNHibernate v2.0.3**.

I've those tables:

- Typology (Id, Description, ..., ExpressionId)
- Expression (Id, Name, Script, Language)

Relations:

- 1 Typology can reference 0 or 1 Expression
- 1 Expression can be referenced by 0 or N Typology

I need to configure mappings so that manipulating the objects I can:

1. Change the `Expression` referenced on a `Typology`, and update it so that on the DB the value of ExpressionId column changes.
2. Delete a reference to an `Expression` on a `Typology`, so that **the ExpressionId will be** `NULL` and the corresponding `Expression` **remains on the DB, even if it is not referenced by any other** `Typology`.
3. Create a new `Expression` object and associate it to an existing (or newly created) `Typology` so that the new `Expression` is saved to DB and `Typology` (eventually created) reference it, like this:

> ```
> Typology typology = _repositoryTypologies.GetById(1);
>
> Expression newExp = new Expression()
> {
>     Name = "S2",
>     Script = "public void Test()",
>     //...
>     Language = "cs"
> };
>
> typology.CompletionScript = newExp;
> _repositoryTypologies.Save(typology);
> ```

4. If possible, if I delete an `Expression`, all the Typologies that reference it, will be updated with `ExpressionId = NULL`.

I already tried with some mappings but I didn't obtained the desired results.
I've been looking a bit here and there but I don't understand yet what is the best mapping for this case. Someone uses `References()` even if there's a 0-1 relation, someone else recommend to use `HasOne()`/`HasMany()`.

These are my actual classes:

```
public class Typology
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    //...
    public virtual Expression CompletionScript { get; set; }
}

public class TypologyMap : ClassMap<Typology>
{   
    public TypologyMap()
    {
        Table("Typologies");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("TypologyId");
        Map(x => x.Description).Column("Description").Not.Nullable();
        //...
        HasOne(x => x.CompletionScript).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }
}

public class Expression
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Script { get; set; }
    public virtual string Language { get; set; }
}

public class ExpressionMap : ClassMap<Expression>
{   
    public ExpressionMap()
    {
        Table("Expressions");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ExpressionId");
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Script);
        Map(x => x.Language);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Expression` will need some kind of collection for its related `Topologies`. Something like this:

```
public class Expression
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Script { get; set; }
    public virtual string Language { get; set; }

    // At its most basic...
    public virtual List<Topology> Topologies { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can map it:

```
public class ExpressionMap : ClassMap<Expression>
{   
    public ExpressionMap()
    {
        Table("Expressions");
        LazyLoad();
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("ExpressionId");
        Map(x => x.Name).Column("Name").Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Script);
        Map(x => x.Language);

        HasMany(x => x.Topologies);
    }
}
```

You should be able to use `References()` on the `Expression` side of the mapping. Although some might recommend `ManyToOne()`. I'm not too sure of their nuances.

While this should provide a functional solution, you'll need to toughen it up a bit by considering access to the collection, cascading, etc.

Comment: Can you please explain a complete working example with my entities? Now, as you can see, I set `HasOne(x => x.CompletionScript).Cascade.SaveUpdate()` on `TypologyMap` but it doesn't work as expected. When I save (see the example) it correctly creates the new `Expression` row on DB, but doesn't change the ExpressionId reference on `Typology`. So I think that something needs to be changed even on `Typology` mapping. Is it correct the `Typology` mapping using `HasOne()`?